# Laravel Eloquent delete with where doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How can I delete rows of table with eloquent and where ? My code is wrong? the code doesn't work!

```
Mode::where('expired','<=',Carbon::now()->toDateString())->delete();
```

Comment: is 'expired' a date field?, try Mode::where('expired','<=',Carbon::now()->toDateString())->get(); and check if there are any results matching the condition, if you dont get any records then the condition doesn' t match for the records

Comment: Thank you . fixed .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `Carbon::now()->toDateString()` format matches with the format of 'expired' column

Comment: Expired field is string

Comment: stores some kind of date as string? how did you get the delete query work btw buddy @MortezaNegahi

Answer (score 0):

If your expired timestamp is in format of `Y-m-d H:i:s` then you can use `toDateTimeString()` in place of `toDateString()`

You can use

```
Mode::where('expired','<=',Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())->delete();
```